# How do I use path the to my VS Code extension's directory in a contributed setting's default value?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension for Vale style linting. It includes a `styles` sub-directory with files for individual style rules. Inside the extension, I'm overriding a config option from another extension in its `package.json` file:

```json
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
        "vale.valeCLI.config": ".vale.ini"
    }
 }
```

The `.vale.ini` file is included in the root directory of the extension itself. Is there a variable that points to the root directory of the current extension? Or a way derive it from an extension ID? The above code does not work for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a [variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) for getting the path to an extension's installation directory in package.json.

I'd take a different approach: let the default setting value be `null`, and then in your extension's code, if the value is `null`, then use the default path. You can create a helper function that gets the value of the setting, and then if the value is not `null`, return that value, and if it is `null`, return the `extensionPath` property of [the `Extension` type](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Extension%3CT%3E). Everywhere you want to use that setting's value, call that helper function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How exactly can I make use of the `extensionPath` property in `package.json`? I have no idea how and where to insert the code :-)

Comment: @TomášBažant you can't use it in package.json. You've misunderstood what I'm saying. Maybe read it again? I'm not sure right now how I can clarify better than what I've already written.

Comment: Ok, i'm nearing.... :-) in my `extension.js` file in the `activate` function, i can do
`vscode.window.showInformationMessage(context.extensionPath);`

and it works, but how do i pass this value back to the `package.json` file where i need it?